# String Index Out of Range Error in Python

Tags: python, string, indexing

I keep getting an "IndexError: string index out of range" error message when I try to execute this code:

```
#function countLetters(word,letter) should count the number of times
#a particular letter appears in a word.

def countLetters(word, letter):

    count=0

    wordlen=len(word)
    num=0
    wordletter=""

    while(num<=wordlen):
        wordletter=word[num]
        if(wordletter==letter):
            count=count+1
        num=num+1
    return count

print(countLetters("banana", "x"))#should print 0
print(countLetters("banana", "a"))#should print 3
print(countLetters("banana", "b"))#should print 1
```

The Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Charlie Chiang\Desktop\9G.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(countLetters("banana", "x"))
  File "C:\Users\Charlie Chiang\Desktop\9G.py", line 10, in countLetters
    var=word[num]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: The code being run and the code you are looking into, seems to me, are different. There is no `var=word[num]` in your source while the `Traceback` seems to think there is

Comment: @shaktimaan: It was close enough; instead of `var` it is `wordletter=word[num]`.

Comment: FYI, I don't know if this is for an assigment, but you can always just use `.count()`. Example: `"banana".count("a")` returns `3`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm taking a class, it was an assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You take it one index too far:

```
while(num<=wordlen):
```

`num` must stay strictly *below* the length:

```
while num < wordlen:
```

because Python sequences are 0-based. A string of length 5 has indices 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4, **not** 5.

Comment: Thank You so much! I feel really stupid now, but at least I know what I did wrong! I can't thank you enough, I've been trying to figure this out for the past 2 days!THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

You are reaching one index too far:

```
while(num<=wordlen):
```

For a text "a" the len("a") is 1 and last letter can be reached by index 0. Your while condition allows trying index 1, which is not available.

## Bonus: counting using Counter

Python stdlib `collections` provides excellent `Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter("banana").get("x", 0)
0
>>> Counter("banana").get("a", 0)
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixing your code:

```
def countLetters(word, letter):

    count=0

    wordlen=len(word)
    num=0
    wordletter=""
    #here, because the index access is 0-based
    #you have to test if the num is less than, not less than or equal to length
    #last index == len(word) -1
    while(num<wordlen):
        wordletter=word[num]
        if(wordletter==letter):
            count=count+1
        num=num+1
    return count

print(countLetters("banana", "x"))#should print 0
print(countLetters("banana", "a"))#should print 3
print(countLetters("banana", "b"))#should print 1
```

more elegant way:
    `str.count` method

```
'banana'.count('x')
'banana'.count('a')
'banana'.count('b')
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the index of the string starts at zero, the highest valid index will be wordlen-1.

Answer (score -1):

The index start at 0, not 1.

Try changing:

```
wordletter = word[num-1]
```

Comment: @f.rodriques The question shows code starting with index 0.